# Nested function alternatives in C++

Tags: c++, function, nested

I want to make a function f() that uses three values to compute its result: a, b, and e. e is dependent on a and b, so technically f() is only a function of a and b. But for the sake of readability, it is easier to look at a function containing the abstraction e than to look at a messier formula containing many a's and b's.

Is there any way to use dependent variables like e without the use of nested functions, which C++ does not allow?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do in code?

Comment: Herb Sutter covered this in one of his gotw, he shows a few ways to simulate it: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/058.htm

Answer (score 4):

C++ does have local variables, which makes this easy:

```
double f(double const a, double const b)
{
    double const e = a * b + b * b * b;
    return a + b + e;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a local struct which can define a static function, which can be used as if its nested function as:

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
   struct local
   {
        static int f(int a, int b, int e)
        {
             return e * (a + b);
        }
   };
   return local::f(a,b, a*b);
}
```

Comment: `e` would be the output of `local::f`, so should be removed from its parameters and calculation...

Comment: @Tony: I described the *technique*, not the *calculation*.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, but if you're just after a way to make your function more readable by introducing a dependent variable, why not just calculate that variable in a separate function called by your main function:

```
float CalculateE(float a, float b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

float f(float a, float b)
{
    float e = CalculateE(a, b);
    return a + b + e;
}
```

Comment: If taking this approach, an option is to put CalculateE in an anonymous namespace immediately above, which emphasises that it's only a supporting function and not intended for direct usage outside the translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
int compute_e(int a, int b)
{
    return whatever;
}

int func(int a, int b)
{
    int e = compute_e(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Your second function doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
int f(int a, int b)
{
    struct LocalFunc
    {
        int operator()(int a, int b)
        {
            return a*b + b*b*b;
        }
    };
    LocalFunc e;
    return e(a,b)*a+b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can write some notes.

```
int FuncSum(int a, int b)
{
    //return the sum of a + b
    return a + b ;
}
```